# .json data in to SqLite Db

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

We have folder path like this  in

> assets-->www-->json-->loadingsheetheadr.json

We tried like this

```
  $.getJSON("loadingsheetheadr.json", function(result){

  });
```

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to answer the question (without a substantial amount of guessing). Where is the page where this javascript is running from?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$.getJSON("json/loadingsheetheadr.json", function(result){

});
```